# AngularJS directive when template is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a little confused about when 'template' in AngularJS directive is rendered. See following code snippets:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.1.5"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <example-directive name="{{name}}"></example-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'First ONE ';
});

app.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: "@"
    },
    template: '<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>',
    controller: function($scope, $element){
      $scope.name = $scope.name + "Second ";
      $scope.name2 = $scope.name + "Second ";
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
      scope.name = scope.name + "Third ";
      $scope.name2 = $scope.name + "Second ";
    }
  }
})
```

It displays "Hello First One" which means none of the first statement in controller and link functions changes the value of name in scope or the change is not reflected in the template.

However, if I changed the directive to

```
template: '<p>Hello {{name2}}!</p>'
```

or change 'name' to two way binding by using '=' instead of '@'

it renders "Hello First ONE Second Second !" as expected.

The plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKUTZXOKZa9zYhKloiuc?p=preview)

So does it mean for one way binding, scope var in template is rendered before controller and link functions kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this:

```
<example-directive name="{{name}}"></example-directive>
```

to this:

```
<example-directive name="name"></example-directive>
```

and this:

```
scope: {
  name: "@"
},
```

to this:

```
scope: {
  name: "="
},
```

And it will work.

## update:

sorry, for not reading the whole question.
here's what's in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' }, then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the parent scope (not component scope).

notice the last part: `The name is read from the parent scope (not component scope)`

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that changing to two way binding will make it work. Just want to know the reason behind it.